How to write Mock Unit Test Code that will Test a class method that downcasts an input argument interface as a concrete class?
I'm writing mock unit test code that will Test a class method that downcasts an input argument interface as a concrete class.
Here is the “System Under Test(SUT)” class called CarWrapperFactory:

public class CarWrapperFactory : ICarWrapperFactory
{
    public ICarWrapper CreateCarWrapper(ICarConfigurationWrapper carConfigurationWrapper)
    {

        // downcasting occurring on next line, and also subsequently invocation of "protected internal" method
        CarConfiguration loggerConfiguration = ((CarConfigurationWrapper)carConfigurationWrapper).GetCarConfigurationAdaptee();

        return new CarWrapper(carConfiguration.CreateCar());
    }
}


In the aforementioned  CarWrapperFactory SUT class, there is downcasting code because it invokes a “protected internal” method called GetCarConfigurationAdaptee.
In my NSubstitute-based Mock Unit Test code, I start off with the following:

ICarConfigurationWrapper carConfigurationWrapperMock = Substitute.For<ICarConfigurationWrapper>();

 // Fill-in-blank code….how to mock the “protected internal” method called GetCarConfigurationAdaptee

ICarWrapperFactory carWrapperFactorySUT = new CarWrapperFactory();

  ICarWrapper carWrapper = carWrapperFactorySUT. CreateCarWrapper(carConfigurationWrapperMock);


How can I write the code for the "Fill-in-blank" code above?
PS: Essentially, I'm trying to adapt/wrap 3rd-party open source Serilog's modules. It's Serilog's bad design. Inside Serilog's LoggerConfiguration , there is a method called "public Logger CreateLogger()" Serilog does Not have a factory for Logger, it instantiates a Logger based using methods in the LoggerConfiguration. It does Not make sense. Here is their code:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/LoggerConfiguration.cs

check my updated answer if you will post more details about task what you want to accomplish I will help more

First of all ICarConfigurationWrapper should contain all methods as a contract of the class
it is bad code design to call protected methods, consider them as private, so you need pull this protected method up in the interface. and you will not need to cast nothing and in your Unit tests you can easy substitute with mock implementation
Protected methods only visible in derived classes
PS carConfiguration.CreateCar() it is not rensposiblity of configuration to create the cars it should be CarFactory class
I would refactor the code in the following way
public class CarWrapperFactory : ICarFactory
{
    private readonly ICarFactory _factory;

    public CarWrapperFactory(ICarFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    public ICar CreateCar(ICarConfiguration configuration)
    {
       //additional logic here
        var car = _factory.CreateCar(configuration);

        return car;
    }
}

the Idea or Wrapper Design pattern to have the same interface but add additional functionality so your Wrapper should implement the same interface as the class which it suppose to wrap
UPDATE: as per discussion in one of my project I've used wrapper around Serilog
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Formatting.Compact;

namespace Framework.Infrastructure.Logging;

class Logger : ILogger
{
    private const string Context = "TraceId";
    private readonly Serilog.Core.Logger _logger;
    private string _traceId;

    public Logger()
    {
        _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console( new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter())
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public void AddTraceId(string traceId)
    {
        _traceId = traceId;
    }

    public void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        _logger.ForContext(Context, _traceId).Information(message);
    }
    public void LogInfo(string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
    {
        _logger.ForContext(Context, _traceId).Information(messageTemplate, propertyValues);
    }

    public void LogTrace(string message)
    {
        _logger.ForContext(Context, _traceId).Debug(message);
    }

    public ITimeLogger LogPerformance(string message)
    {
        return new TimeLogger(this, message);
    }

    public void LogError(Exception exception, string messageTemplate)
    {
        _logger.ForContext(Context, _traceId).Error(exception, messageTemplate);
    }
}

here is interface
public interface ILogger
{
    void AddTraceId(string traceId);
    void LogInfo(string message);
    void LogTrace(string message);
    ITimeLogger LogPerformance(string message);
    void LogError(Exception exception, string messageTemplate);
    void LogInfo(string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues);
}

hope this works for you

Thanks. But it's a wrapper( i.e., adapter as in adapter design pattern).  The "protected internal" method retrieves the adaptee object that I do Not want to expose in the interface( which in turn means exposing it to the client code).

@crazyTech Check my answer I believe you misunderstood how to apply and implement wrapper pattern it is not like you implemented in your post and adapter it is not a wrapper

@crazyTech your problem not in unit tests it is in the code give me more details and I will help you

Thanks.  Essentially, I'm trying to adapt/wrap 3rd-party open source Serilog's modules.  It's Serilog's bad design.  Inside Serilog's LoggerConfiguration , there is a method called "public Logger CreateLogger()"       Serilog does Not have a factory for Logger,  it instantiates a Logger based using methods in the LoggerConfiguration.  It does Not make sense.  Here is their code:   https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/LoggerConfiguration.cs

@crazyTech Got it had the same concerns and I wrote my wrapper around it check my updated answer! if you using ASP.NET Core you can use UseSerilog() extension method to completely substitute .NET  logger and use Dependency Injection

Thanks.  However, the code that you provided will keep instantiating a new LoggerConfiguration with No arguments.  In my use case, I need to populate a LoggerConfiguration with arguments.  I blame the Bad Design on Serilog.  They should have a factory that generates Loggers.  A configuration ( i.e., LoggerConfiguration) entity should Never have API that generates Loggers.  Configuration entities should be like simple POCOs/DTOs.
